# Getting only first value of json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Thanks in advance.

I have a json file stored in s3 bucket. I am referring that for any re-directs. Below is an example json file.

```
{
  "redirects" :[
  {
    "url" : "/xxx/index.html", 
    "redirect_url": "/yyy/index.html", 
    "statusCode": 302 
  },
  {
    "url" : "/aaaa/index.html",
    "redirect_url": "/bbb/index.html", 
    "statusCode": 301      
  },
  {
    "url" : "/ccc/ddd/index.html", 
    "redirect_url": "/eeee/index.html", 
    "statusCode": 301 
  }
]
}
```

However only the first entry of the redirects is taken by lambda and rest are ignored. Below is my python script for redirects. I have cloudfront in front.

```
import boto3
import json
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
base_url= "testsite_com" ###Cannot post any site address on stackoverflow

def lambda_handler (event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    print(event)
    content_object = s3.Object('cbtest.cb-infra.com', 'config/redirects.json')
    file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_content = json.loads(file_content)

    for entries in json_content["redirects"]:
        old_url = entries["url"]
        redirect_uri = entries["redirect_url"]
        status_code = entries["statusCode"]
        new_url= base_url + redirect_uri
        print(old_url)
        if request["uri"] == old_url :
            response = {
                    'status': status_code,
                    'statusDescription': 'Found',
                    'headers': {
                        'location': [{
                            'key': 'Location',
                            'value': new_url
                        }]
                    }
                }
            print(response)
            print("uri matched: ", request["uri"], redirect_uri)
            return response    
        else : 
            print("uri : ", request["uri"])
            return request
```

Redirect for only 1st url i.e /xxx/index.html works. Rest are not getting redirected.

Comment: Your URL redirection lookups would be more efficient if your JSON file simply mapped the URLs e.g. `{ "/xxx/index.html": { "redirect_url": "/yyy/index.html", "statusCode": 302 } }`. You would not need to iterate over the list of redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning after the first iteration in the `for` loop, either from the `if` or `else` statement, in Python a function exits after returning.